# PHP use() Function In This Situation

Tags: php, closures, scandir

I am trying to loop through a directory and only show files, no folders. I have come across this code from another person on SO, and while it works, I do not understand how.

```
function scandir_nofolders($d) {
    return array_filter(scandir($d), function ($f) use($d) {
       return ! is_dir($d . "/" . $f);
   });
}
```

So assume I have running this with the following code:

```
print_r(scandir_nofolders('/xampp');
```

Where I struggle is the inner most return value when the is_dir() function is determining whether the supplied parameter is a directory or not.

You'd think the code would translate to

```
return ! is_dir('/xampp'./.'/xampp');
```

Notice how in the above example $d and $f are the same. If you call an anonymous function and use the use function with in this case $d, wouldn't $d and $f be the exact same, because $f is essentially copying what $d is?  Obviously I am not looking for /xampp//xampp (which is what I think the code would translate to), yet this works perfectly. Could someone explain what this code is actually doing? I imagine if anything, I have the true purpose of the `use()` function misunderstood.

Comment: `use()` is the way to propagate topmost variables to closures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you happen to know Javascript, the equivalent code there would be:

```
function scandir_nofolders(d) {
    return scandir(d).filter(function (f) {
       return !is_dir(d + "/" + f);
   });
}
```

What's happening here? The innermost `is_dir` call uses a concatenation of `d` and `f`. `d` is the same `d` as was passed into the function, `f` is the value of one element in the array returned by `scandir`. In Javascript, variables of the parent scope of a function are available just like that inside a function.

In PHP, that is not the case.

```
$d = 'foo';
function () {
    // no access to $d here
}
```

To make `$d` available inside the anonymous function, you need to "pass it through" using `use`. `$d` will be the parent directory and `$f` will be an entry within that directory.

Also see [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/476)

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same:

`$d` - is directory you pass for scandir_nofolders as argument (in your case `'/xampp'`

`$f` - is a single item in this directory (file, directory, . or ..)

To make a check you can simply add echo to this function:

```
function scandir_nofolders($d) {
    return array_filter(scandir($d), function ($f) use($d) {
       echo $d.' '.$f."<br />";
       return ! is_dir($d . "/" . $f);
   });
}
```

and you will see the difference.

In closures, closure argument is the element on which you want to make an operation (for example sorting, or in your case displaying/checking item) and in `use` you can add other variables as in your case you need to pass directory in which those item (files) are placed to make check using `is_dir` function

Comment: But if `d` is the directory, when you call `function($f)`, `use($d)`, doesn't that just substitute $f for $d?

Comment: @user3412869 No, $d will have all the time `/xampp` value, and `$f` could be also directory name but inside `/xampp` folder so for example `scripts` but they are never the same. Have you run this code with echo? I think this explains everything.